# How to scrape website that comes up with 403 error?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the following web page
https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamaneurology/article-abstract/2696970
but getting an error.

```
url ='https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamaneurology/article-abstract/2696970'
result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Result:

> ## 403 Forbidden
>
> Request forbidden by
> administrative rules.

You can access the web page with no credentials, so not sure why I get 'Request forbidden' error while scraping.

Comment: It's probably looking at your HTTP user agent string to check that it's a human with a browser

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you should add a `user-agent` to your request:

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
```

You can check your own headers, send by the browser via opening dev tools and take a look under network section. [Read more about `user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).

##### Example

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
url ='https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamaneurology/article-abstract/2696970'
result = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: I added headers, it still get the same error